# How can I make Table of Defer[Sqrt[3i] - k Sqrt[3j]]?

Tags: evaluation, output-formatting

I am trying to make a Table of expressions `Defer[Sqrt[3i] + 2 Sqrt[3j]]`, e.g

```
Defer[Sqrt[27 ] + 2 Sqrt[108]] == Sqrt[27 ] + 2 Sqrt[108]
```

With Table, I tried

```
TableForm@
 Activate@
  Table[Inactivate@Defer[Sqrt[3 i] + 2 Sqrt[3 j]] == 
    Sqrt[3 i] + 2 Sqrt[3 j] , {i, 1, 20}, {j, 21, 40}]
```

How can I tell Mathematica Out put in the form

```
Sqrt[27] + 2 Sqrt[108] == 3 Sqrt[3] + 12 Sqrt[3] == 15 Sqrt[3]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
func = Defer[Sqrt[#] + 2 Sqrt[#2]] == (Defer[# + #2] &)[Sqrt[#], 2 Sqrt[#2]] == 
    Sqrt[#] + 2 Sqrt[#2] &;

Table[func[3 i, 3 j], {i, 20}, {j, 21, 40}] // TableForm
```

Just keep in mind that `Defer` is nothing but a function with `HoldAll` attribute that will disappear when being output in notebook (to be more precise, when it passes through `MakeBoxes` stage).

Comment: How can I remove when `3 i` and `3j` get the same value?

Comment: @minhthien_2016 The simplest solution I can think of at the moment is using `Nothing` e.g. `Table[If[i == j, Nothing, func[3 i, 3 j]], {i, 20}, {j, 20}]`

Comment: @xzczd Can I format like this 
`Sqrt[27] + 2 Sqrt[108] == Sqrt[3*3^2] + 2 Sqrt[3*6^2]  = 3 Sqrt[3] + 12 Sqrt[3] == 15 Sqrt[3]`?

Comment: @Laurenso It's possible, but more advanced, because evaluation like `3×3^2` doesn't happen internally, so you need something more than evaluation control: `trans = Sqrt[#] /. {a_. Sqrt[b_] :> Sequence[b, a], a_ :> Sequence[1, a]} &;
template = Defer[Sqrt[# #2^2] + 2 Sqrt[#3 #4^2]] &;
func2 = template[trans[#], trans[#2]] &;
func2[27, 108]`

Answer (score 2):

```
t0 = Table[
    Inactivate[Sqrt[3 i] + 2 Sqrt[3 j]], {i, 1, 20}, {j, 21, 40}] /. 
   Inactive[Sqrt] :> Sqrt;

t1 = Table[
    Inactivate[Sqrt[3 i] + 2 Sqrt[3 j]], {i, 1, 20}, {j, 21, 40}] /. 
   Inactive[Times] :> Times;

t2 = Table[Sqrt[3 i] + 2 Sqrt[3 j], {i, 1, 20}, {j, 21, 40}];

(MapThread[List, {t0, t1, t2}, 2] // 
    Replace[#, {a_, b_, c_} :> a == b == c, 2] &) /. 
  Inactive[Sqrt][a_] :> Sqrt[ToString@a] // TableForm
```

A sample of the output looks like:

[image]

Comment: A bit different from OP's desired output, I'm afraid. In `t0`, `Plus` and `Sqrt` should be `Inactivate`d, I think.

Comment: Thanks for spotting. I wanted to retain the `i` and `j` so it is a bit different.